# ant fresh_install error/build failed

Tags: postgresql, dspace

Hello Stack overflow members. I've tried installing Dspace on my machine a couple of times, but I am stuck at the ant fresh_install bit of it. What could be the error and how would I fix it to run?

Below is what I receive when I run ant fresh_install in the cmd.
Thank you.

> C:\DSpace-dspace-5.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer>ant fresh_install
>   Buildfile: C:\DSpace-dspace-5.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer\build.xml
>
> init_installation:
>
> init_configs:
>
> test_database:

```
 [java] 2016-06-02 22:48:47,014 INFO  org.dspace.core.ConfigurationManager @ Loading system provided config property (-Ddspace.configuration): config/dspace.cfg
 [java] 2016-06-02 22:48:47,043 INFO  org.dspace.core.ConfigurationManager @ Using default log4j provided log configuration.  If unintended, check your dspace.cfg for (log.init.config)
 [java] 2016-06-02 22:48:47,266 WARN  org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DataSourceInit @ Exception initializing DB pool
 [java] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace"
 [java]     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
 [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
 [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:75)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:974)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
 [java]     at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DataSourceInit.getDatasource(DataSourceInit.java:140)
 [java]     at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseManager.initDataSource(DatabaseManager.java:1440)
 [java]     at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.main(DatabaseUtils.java:83)
 [java] Caught exception:
 [java] java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace"
 [java]     at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DataSourceInit.getDatasource(DataSourceInit.java:171)
 [java]     at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseManager.initDataSource(DatabaseManager.java:1440)
 [java]     at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.main(DatabaseUtils.java:83)
 [java] Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace"
 [java]     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
 [java]     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
 [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
 [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:75)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:974)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
 [java]     at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DataSourceInit.getDatasource(DataSourceInit.java:140)
 [java]     ... 2 more
```

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\DSpace-dspace-5.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer\build.xml:797: Java returned: 1
>
> Total time: 3 seconds
>
> C:\DSpace-dspace-5.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer>

Answer (score 1):

Like it says in your error message -- the database username + password you set in `build.properties` is incorrect. Make sure you've set up a `dspace` user for your database and that its password is correctly specified in the DSpace configuration. See step 4 in the [DSpace 5 installation instructions](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-Installation).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Mine was solved by editing the correct cfg file, /dspace/config/local.cfg

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem its no `pgcrypto` extension in `pgadmin` database
**the solve is** run this query manually :
`Create extension pgcrypto;` in `pgadmin` query window,
good luck

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing all the unused clusters (pg_lsclusters, I had 4 Postgres-versions/clusters).

Also I removed all the unused versions of client and server packages:

e.g.

```
apt-get --purge remove postgresql-10 postgresql-client-10 postgresql-server-dev-9.4 postgresql-contrib-9.3 postgresql-client-9.4 postgresql-client-9.3
```

I suppose the problem may occur if you use different versions of postgresql client and server.